# Consistent 100% height for bootstrap multiple grid row

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to design a simple responsive design consisting of two panels that should be side by side for medium to large screens and one on top of the other for phone like screens.

When the panels are side by side they should have 100% height and when stacked they should have 50% height.

Problem is that for medium and large screens the height of divs stays 50% instead of going to 100%.
In the end I would like to have the entire screen divided into two colored sections. now this happens only for extra small screens.

Thank you!

**CSS**

```
html, body, .container, .row {
height: 100%;
}

.left-panel{
    background-color: red;
}

.right-panel{
    background-color: teal;
}

.col-sm-8 .col-sm-4 .col-lg-9 col-lg-3{
    height: 100%;
}
.col-xs-12{
    height: 50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9 col-xs-12 left-panel">
        left panel
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 right-panel">
        right panel
    </div>
</div>
```

Also find the code at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/59e9x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a media query to target mobile only

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59E9x/1/

html receives min-height: 100%;

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

panels stay at 100% height

```
.left-panel,
.right-panel {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and for mobile we set them at 50% .

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    height: 50%;
}
```

i would not attach extra styles to bootraps default classes (ex: col-sm-8,col-sm-4) . these where build to do 1 thing and changing the behavior is not recommended